# Server and client don't send file, how can I make it work?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to create a client-server file transfer using python socket but i cant make it work

For example I used this from a tutorial:

Server:

```py
import socket, os, sys

def Main():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    try:
        s.connect(('10.255.255.255', 1))
        IP = s.getsockname()[0]
    except:
        IP = '127.0.0.1'
    finally:
        s.close()
    print(IP)
    host = IP
    port = 50001
    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind((host,port))
    print("server Started")
    s.listen(1)
    while True:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print("Connection from: " + str(addr))
        filename = ''
        while True:
            data = c.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            if not data:
                break
            filename += data
        print("from connected user: " + filename)
        c.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Client:

```
host = '192.168.1.90'
port = 50001

s = socket.socket()
s.connect((host, port))

Filename = 'prova3.txt'
s.send(Filename.encode('utf-8'))
s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
data = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
print(data)
s.close()
host = '192.168.1.90'
port = 50001
s = socket.socket()
s.connect((host, port))
Filename = 'prova3.txt'
s.send('prova3.txt')
s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
data = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
print(data)
s.close()
```

Now this client and server connect to each other but don't send file, what's wrong?

Comment: There’s no file sending code written and you close the socket before trying to read the file

Comment: Thanks, could you help me to fix it?